# Cannot convert to a pointer type, Casting structs

Tags: c, pointers

When casting a struct to a pointer i'm getting a "Cannot convert to a pointer type" error.

I' trying to cast a struct of type ObjectExtended into a pointer of ObjectBase, the first member of ObjectExtended is a pointer to ObjectBase so it should work.

Here's the code:

```
typedef struct ObjectBase
{
    int integer1;
    int integer2;
}ObjectBase;

typedef struct ObjectExtended
{
    ObjectBase* baseObj;
    char* string;
}ObjectExtended;

int main(int argc,char** argv)
{
    ObjectExtended* objExtended = malloc(sizeof(ObjectExtended));
    objExtended->string = "TEST_OBJECT";

    objExtended->baseObj = malloc(sizeof(ObjectBase));
    objExtended->baseObj->integer1 = 10;
    objExtended->baseObj->integer2 = 11;

    printf("Extended Object:\n");
    printf("\tString: %s\n",objExtended->string);
    printf("\tInt1: %i\n",objExtended->baseObj->integer1);
    printf("\tInt2: %i\n",objExtended->baseObj->integer2);

    ObjectBase* objBase = (ObjectBase*)(*objExtended);
    printf("Base Object:\n");
    printf("\tInt1: %i\n",objBase->integer1);
    printf("\tInt2: %i\n",objBase->integer2);

    free(objExtended->baseObj);
    free(objExtended);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You must place the structure itself as the first member of your derived class (so to speak), not a pointer to it.

Comment: That's correct: you cannot cast a struct to a pointer (`ObjectBase* objBase = (ObjectBase*)(*objExtended);`). They aren't the same thing. However, you can do this: `ObjectBase* objBase = (ObjectBase*)objExtended;`

Comment: is there a way to use a pointer instead of the struct

Answer (score 0):

```
    ObjectBase* objBase = (ObjectBase*)(*objExtended);
```

should be

```
    ObjectBase* objBase = (ObjectBase*)objExtended;
```

I think.  You don't need to dereference `objExtended`.

Comment: that would work if the pointer to ObjectBase in ObjectExtended wasn't a pointer

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want the `ObectBase` "component" of `ObjectExtended`. Just use the name of the field

```
ObjectBase* objBase = objExtended->baseObj;
```

which is just another spelling of

```
ObjectBase* objBase = (*objExtended).baseObj;
```

For the object-like casting, it is simply not defined in C, only scalar types are allowed in casts, and you shouldn't try to cheat the type system of C.

Comment: But I should be able to cast it to its first member, or am I wrong?

Comment: @Helios41: You can convert a structure _pointer_ to a _pointer_ to it's first member.

Comment: @Helios41, you may, as long as you can always guarantee that it is the first member. But that property is difficult to maintain, and casting takes off all possible type checking. Using just the struct field as it is defined and perhaps impose some naming convention is much easier to check for you and for the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to

```
  ObjectBase* objBase = (ObjectBase *)objExtended; //Compiles and running, but gives wrong answer.
```

For correct answer you can write

```
 ObjectBase* objBase = (ObjectBase *)objExtended->baseObj;
```

or

```
 ObjectBase* objBase = objExtended->baseObj;
```